# 'Render Properties' keyframes always showing in timeline, and no way to hide them?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

In a scene I've made, I animated the exposure in the 'Render Properties' tab, and as expected it shows the keyframes for this in the timeline. However, these keyframes remain in the timeline permanently, even when selecting another object and they get in the way when trying to animate. I want to hide them so that they only show when I want them to. What is going on and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a way in the timeline, but if you animate in the graph editor you can tap on filter and uncheck scenes:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that *Only Keyframes from Selected Channels* is enabled under *View* settings of the *Timeline Editor*.

[image: selected keyframes]